# Style error after importing SLD of QGIS in GeoServer Layer

Tags: qgis, geoserver, wms, sld, web

I have a layer in GeoServer which opens when default style like "polygon" is selected in the publishing menu

[image: Layer with default style]

but when I change its style in WMS Settings, for which I have created a new style by importing the SLD of same dateset from QGIS,
it shows the error like, ERROR: invalid input syntax for type double precision
and the layer does not open.

[image: error with imported SLD]

However while Validating the imported SLD, no errors were encountered.

[image: Validation of SLD without any error]

The SLD used is as follows:

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 10</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 10</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#440154</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>11 - 20</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>11 - 20</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#24868e</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>21 - 30</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>21 - 30</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#5dc962</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>31 - 40</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>31 - 40</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#8fd744</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>41 - 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>41 - 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>50</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e120</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>> 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>> 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>55</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e4e419</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

How to rectify this error.

Comment: You don't say how you created the style in QGIS but that is not a good style

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SLD filter is converted into an SQL where clause and passed to PostGIS, so the lines:

```
          <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal></ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
```

become something like:

```
where rainfall=''
```

but `rainfall` is a double so it can't be empty (as it is in all your filters) you probably want something like:

```
          <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
            <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
            <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>10.0</ogc:Literal>
          </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ian Turton. I got the logic

Answer (score 1):

If someone stuck with such problem then kindly refer to [GeoServer Manual, Tutorial: Styling data with CSS](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html)

and read the different ogc:Filter properties like

`<ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>`
`<ogc:PropertyIsBetween>`
`<ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>`

and in case if you choose `<ogc:PropertyIsBetween>`
do consider the lower and upper boundary as given here

````
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>PERSONS</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>2000000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>4000000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>```


my SLD is as follows

```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:se="http://www.opengis.net/se" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.1.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <se:Name>rainfall_forecast</se:Name>
      <se:FeatureTypeStyle>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>0 - 10</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>0 - 10</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>0.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>10.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
              </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#440154</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>11 - 20</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>11 - 20</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
                              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>11.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>20.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
              </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#24868e</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>21 - 30</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>21 - 30</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>21.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>30.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
              </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#5dc962</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>31 - 40</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>31 - 40</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>31.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>40.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
              </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyIsNull>
                <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              </ogc:PropertyIsNull>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#8fd744</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>41 - 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>41 - 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:LowerBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>41.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:LowerBoundary>
              <ogc:UpperBoundary>
                <ogc:Literal>50.0</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:UpperBoundary>
            </ogc:PropertyIsBetween>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#c7e120</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
        <se:Rule>
          <se:Name>> 50</se:Name>
          <se:Description>
            <se:Title>> 50</se:Title>
          </se:Description>
          <ogc:Filter xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
            <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
              <ogc:PropertyName>rainfall</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>51</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <se:PolygonSymbolizer>
            <se:Fill>
              <se:SvgParameter name="fill">#e4e419</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Fill>
            <se:Stroke>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke">#232323</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-width">1</se:SvgParameter>
              <se:SvgParameter name="stroke-linejoin">bevel</se:SvgParameter>
            </se:Stroke>
          </se:PolygonSymbolizer>
        </se:Rule>
      </se:FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
````

and the layer/output looks like

[image: styled layer]